# Values of V8 NamedProperty object properties are not shown in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, v8, node-inspector

We are using the V8 version 5.3.332 in my Android App. We are trying to debug the javascript using the Node-Inspector(0.11.3)(Also tried with Eclipse Chrome Dev Tools) but strangely values of certain object properties are not shown when we hover or seen it in scoped variables section. This behaviour is particularly seen for the V8 objects which has Named Property handler attached. If the V8 object is prepared with SetAccessor then values of all properties are shown properly.

We observed that, For Named Property objects, its NamedGetter is not called for its properties so all properties are being shown as undefined.

We are preparing the V8 object as below

Local funTem = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate,callback);
Local inst = funTem->InstanceTemplate();
inst->SetNamedPropertyHandler(NamedGetter,NamedSetter,NamedQueryCallback,0,NamedEnumerator);

When Debugger tries to evaluate the expression of this object, only its NamedEnumarator is called but not its NamedGetter.

Can you please let me know what could be the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this was also asked and answered on the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-dev/wTYrzdx4Y3Y.